# Referencing multiword model object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

This could be simple but it is really giving me headache. I have a muiltiword model `ListingImages` that is linked to another model `Listing`. I am retrieving the `Listing` data and using it to access objects of the `ListingImages`. However, I am not getting the desired result. Here are my files.

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ListingImages(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                          verbose_name='Listing Images')

    def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
        title = instance.listing.listing_title
        slug = slugify(title)
        return "listings_pics/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)
```

views.py

```
    def index(request):
        context = {
            'listings': Listing.objects.filter(status=True)
        }
        return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)
```

snippet of template `index.html`

```
    <!--Listing start-->
<div class="property-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-40">
    <div class="property-inner">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="single-properties.html"><img src="{{ listing.listingImages.image_url.url }}" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="property-feature">
                <li>
                    <span class="area"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.land_size }} SqFt</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="bed"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bed.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.bedrooms }}</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="bath"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bath.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.bathrooms }}</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="parking"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/parking.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.car_spaces }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left">
                <h3 class="title"><a href="single-properties.html">{{ listing.listing_title }}</a></h3>
                <span class="location"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/marker.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.city }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="type-wrap">
                    <span class="price">Kshs {{ listing.property.price }}</span>
                    <span class="type">{{ listing.property.get_for_sale_rent_display }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Listing end-->
```

However, in the template, I am not getting the image url, but instead I am getting a `<img src="(unknown)" alt="">`. I don't what I am doing wrong, also, I am not sure how to reference the multiword model `ListingImages`, whether it should be `listingImages` or `listing-images` or `listing_images`.

Comment: Can you post more of the template in `index.html`? Do you want to show more than 1 image per listing?

Comment: Actually, for now I am showing a single image, but later, I will have to display more images. I have not been able to upload multiple images for the listings as per the requirements, but I am still working on that.

Comment: I have added more code to the `index.html` as requested.

Comment: Where the `status` field is coming from?

Comment: @heemayl, sorry, I only added part of the model that I thought was important for the question, the models have other fields that are not disclosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answer to your question: the correct call would be `listing.listingimages_set.all()` - it'll return a queryset of all listing images of a specific listing instance.

Also, I would advice against passing a queryset to the django template. I think it's better to build the template context out of python primitives and pass it. This way it's easier to debug and reason about it:

```
def index(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(status=True).prefetch_related('listingimages_set')
    context = {
        'listings': [
            {
                'title': listing.listing_title,
                'images': list(listing.listingimages_set.all()),
            } for listing in listings
        ]
    }
    return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)
```

Then you can refer to the image of a listing in your template as

```
<ul>
{% for listing in listings %}
    <li>
        {{ listing.title }}
        <ul>
        {% for image in listing.images %}
            <li>{{ image.image_url }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is, of course, just an example. But it shows that this way you have more control over your template context, and can debug its contents before it ends up in the rendered HTML page

Btw, the most common and adopted convention is to call models with a single noun. E.g. `ListingImage` instead of `ListingImages`.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct, bit it's absolutely not better to pass a list rather than a queryset.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've changed the wording so it's more clear that this is my opinion instead of absolute truth :)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, I realized that I was reverse calling the object with ManyToOne relationship. I will try your answer and accept it as you have given detail information on the same.

Comment: @valignatev, I tried your answer using the view to query and it works well. However, I had other fields that I didn't add to the `Listing` model with relationships from other models. Using your approach gave me a bit of problems. For example getting this in the template: `{{ listing.property.car_spaces }}`. Is there a way you could suggest I alter the queryset to give me this desired results?

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing more about the models structure.