# Multi-word django model naming convention

Tags: python, django, django-models, naming-conventions, django-orm

I have a django model called ProfilePicture, i've renamed it from Profile_Picture to ProfilePicture so that it will fit python naming conventions. Right now, i am accessing it something like this `request.user.profilepicture`. I would like to know if it's possible to change it so that i can access it like this: `request.user.profile_picture` or if there is a better way of doing things because `request.user.profilepicture` looks weird

i've seen the answer that is suggested here: [Referencing multiword model object in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796804/referencing-multiword-model-object-in-django)

however, i've tried `request.user.profilepicture_set.all()` and it just says that the attribute does not exist. Even if it does, it still feels a bit wrong.

Comment: seems like a case of XY problem; you don't need to create a "ProfilePicture" model in the first place, but just create a User model with all the needed attribute.
in fact i hardly remember having ever to call a multiwords model name in all my django projects

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to keep profile_picture of users, there is no need to create additional Model as you did. You can use Django User model and AbstractUser it allows you to add new custom fields.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images')
```

Then you will be able to access to the image

For more detailed information check the link below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user